# unable to read heart rate service over Bluetooth

Tags: python, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, sensors, heartrate

I am looking to create a simple python script that reads heart rate data from a Polar sensor over Bluetooth. I have read through a lot of other posts and cannot find something simple that I am able to successfully execute.

I have the device MAC address for the Polar wearable. I know the service UUID for the value I want to read (0x180D for HR). I don't care much about which library or service I use, but I cannot seem to get this to work.

I am able to have my script successfully recognize the Polar sensor, however, I cannot figure out how to read the value from this. I have downloaded a Bluetooth Scanner app for my phone which is able to successfully connect and read the value, so I know it should be easy to do and cannot figure out how to write this up.

Any help would be tremendously appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Which platform are you using? What are you writing the code on?

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the [Bluetooth assigned 16-bit UUIDs numbers](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/) then you are correct that `0x180D` is the Heart Rate service

[image]

It will be the Heart Rate Measurement Characteristic `0x2A37` that will have the values you are seeking:

[image]

I don't have a device to test this with and I don't know what platform you are writing the code for.

As a result I've used the [bleak](https://github.com/hbldh/bleak) library as that is the most cross platform library.

The example also subscribes to notifications from the device rather than reads the value. This is a more typical way to get values that are regularly updating.

```py
import asyncio
import bitstruct
import struct

from bleak import BleakClient


HR_MEAS = "00002A37-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"


async def run(address, debug=False):

    async with BleakClient(address) as client:
        connected = await client.is_connected()
        print("Connected: {0}".format(connected))

        def hr_val_handler(sender, data):
            """Simple notification handler for Heart Rate Measurement."""
            print("HR Measurement raw = {0}: {1}".format(sender, data))
            (rr_int,
             nrg_expnd,
             snsr_cntct_spprtd,
             snsr_detect,
             hr_fmt,
             ) = bitstruct.unpack("p3b1b1b1b1b1<", data)
            if hr_fmt:
                hr_val, = struct.unpack_from("<H", data, 1)
            else:
                hr_val, = struct.unpack_from("<B", data, 1)
            print(f"HR Value: {hr_val}")

        await client.start_notify(HR_MEAS, hr_val_handler)

        while await client.is_connected():
            await asyncio.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    address = ("xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx")  # Change to address of device
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(run(address))
```

You can read more about the Heart Rate Measure value is constructed in:

https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/gatt-specification-supplement-6/

Comment: thanks for sharing that code. Despite the bug in it, that was a great start for me to get connected to my Polar H9 and then continue to get the R-R intervals also.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the bug. I've corrected the bitstruct unpack statement to include the 3 padding bits. I think you need the little endian marker (`<`) in there because the bluetooth data is in little endian format.

Comment: you're misunderstanding Endian-ness. In this case, we are unpacking the bits from a single byte. Therefore big vs little endian has no effect. Your assumption in the original code about that "<" character working on a bit-wise level is why you had the bug and still do, even after you revised your code. You are still getting those 5 flags mixed up. While working to fix the bug, I tried the pattern with both "<" and ">" there and it had no effect. It does matter later on things like the "<H" pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Although the code example from @ukBaz is useful and will accidentally show the correct broadcast HR in some cases, the part that unpacks the 5 bit flags is completely wrong (in wrong bit order and shifted by 3 bits). I discovered the problem when I was also trying to decode the other data such as R-R intervals and its flag was always wrong.

To correct the flags, change the bitstruct.unpack() lines as I've done below. The corrected code then is:

```
import asyncio
import bitstruct
import struct
from bleak import BleakClient

HR_MEAS = "00002A37-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"

async def run(address):

    async with BleakClient(address) as client:
        connected = await client.is_connected()
        print("Connected: {0}".format(connected))

        def hr_val_handler(sender, data):
            """Simple notification handler for Heart Rate Measurement."""
            (unused, rr_int, nrg_expnd, snsr_cntct_spprtd, snsr_detect, hr_fmt) \
                = bitstruct.unpack("b3b1b1b1b1b1", data)
            if hr_fmt:
                hr_val, = struct.unpack_from("<H", data, 1)  # uint16
            else:
                hr_val, = struct.unpack_from("<B", data, 1)  # uint8
            print("HR: {0:3} bpm. Complete raw data: {1} ".format(hr_val, data.hex(sep=':')))

        await client.start_notify(HR_MEAS, hr_val_handler)

        while await client.is_connected():
            await asyncio.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    address = ("xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx")  # Change to address of device
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(run(address))
```

Comment: If I want to use your code to obtain the values of a bycicle cadence sensor all I need to do is replace HR_MEAS = "00002A37-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB" with the correct UUID of my cadence sensor C_MEAS = "00001618-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"? Thank you for your help. Ivo