# Reading heart-rate data from a Polarbelt with a Raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I am trying to retrieive heart-rate date from a polar belt to use as part of emotion recognition algorithm. I am using a Raspberry pi 3b with raspbian. I am able to connect to the device with bluetoothctl When I open info I get a list of the UUID´s

Here is where it stops. I have tried to use hcitool according to the example below, but that does not work. When I try to connect I get the message: Connection Refused(111)

```
$ sudo gatttool -i hci1 -b 00:22:D0:33:1E:0F -I
[   ][00:22:D0:33:1E:0F][LE]> connect
[CON][00:22:D0:33:1E:0F][LE]>
```

So I tried to use bleak and pygatt and I´m not able to make this work. I am quite a newbee, so I am probably doing something wrong. But now I have run out of ideas. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: A similar question was asked a couple of hours ago and has already received an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72539419/7473793

Answer (score 2):

`hciattach`, `hciconfig`, `hcitool`, `hcidump`, `rfcomm`, `sdptool`, `ciptool`, and `gatttool` were [deprecated by the BlueZ project](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?id=b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617) in 2017. If you are following a tutorial that uses them, there is a chance that it might be out of date.

For testing it is best to use the `bluetoothctl` tool.

You say that you have successfully connected and get a list of UUIDs. Was `00002A37-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB` one of them?

If it is then select that inside `bluetoothctl` e.g.

```
gatt.select-attribute 00002a37-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

If that is succussful then you should be able to read the value with:

```
gatt.read
```

Or to test notifications:

```
gatt.notify on
```

This should start data being displayed from the belt.

`gatt.notify off` will stop the data being sent.

If you have this working with `bluetoothctl` then reproducing it with Python should be done with confidence that the RPi and belt are able to connect successfully.

There is an example of building a BLE client with Python at:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63751113/7721752

I noticed in your `gatttool` example you are using `hci1` rather than the more typical value of `hci0`. This is normally the case if you have added a USB BLE dongle. I the above example you would have to change `ADAPTER_PATH = '/org/bluez/hci0'` to end with `hci1`.

There is also the example with Bleak at:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72541361/7721752

For `bleak` to select an alternative adapter would add the adapter address to the `BleakClient` e.g.:

```
async with BleakClient(address, adapter="yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy") as client:
```

Comment: Thank you for all the useful information!. I will give it a new try with your suggestions when I continue the task next term!